# How is this possible to have 2 replicas in 2-node Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

My understanding is that Kafka replication requires quorum server setup which is `2*[replica factor] + 1`.

I however managed to create a topic with replica factor 2 with 2 servers and it does seem to work.

Why is this possible at all? Does it have any side affects by using 2 servers only?

Comment: Maybe it works until something goes down.